# Xamarin live player - fails to deploy app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

i have paired my phone with live player and it connects. But i am getting this error MessageBox when deploying to liveplayer paired Android phone:

[image]

These all are in the same PCL project within a solution, and it is consistent in terms of target versions etc with other PCL projects. Targeting .NetStandard 1.4

The app deploys perfectly to emulator and also to the phone if i disable Xamarin Player in the Tools > Options > Xamarin > Others.

So the problem lies within live player...

Any help would be highly appreciated coz it's killing me to tweak UI changes and deploy the app each time...

Thanks

Comment: I tried to lookup this issue for I wanted to use xamarin live player for the above said issue, however after going through the xamarin forums thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101166/live-not-playing-nice-with-prism#latest I scraped the idea of using it for now.